# Javamail Android - MessageCountListener.messagesAdded doesn't provide message flags nor messageID

Tags: android, imap, jakarta-mail, fetch

I'm developing Android IMAP client based on JavaMail-Android library. I use fetch method of IMAPFolder by providing MessageCountListener. When there is a new message on a folder, the MessageCountListener.messagesAdded is called with the IMAPMesssage object given. Unfortunatelly the provided snapshot does not have flags nor message ID set. When I try to call IMAPFolder.fetch with FetchProfile.Item.FLAGS set, the result is the same.
Why are the flags not set?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

The listener only announces the presence of new messages.  When you call Message.getFlags, it should fetch the flags for the new message.  The "fetch" method can be used to pre-fetch the flags for a bunch of messages all at once, but isn't necessary.

How are you determining that the flags are not set?

If you turn on session debugging, what does the debug output show?